# how to add border to "transparent" image in pixlr.com?

Tags: pixlr

How to  add border to "transparent" non rectangular curvy image in pixlr.com? can anybody help? I don't know how to use photoshop or other image editing softwares. Is there a way to add border to transparent non rectangular curvy image online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to adding a border to an irregular shape using Pixlr online is to add an Outer Glow.

Right click on the layer -> select Layer Styles. Select Outer Glow.

- Opacity: 100
- Hardness: 10
- Size: (Pick)

If your border is going to be a rectangle or oval than you can use the Drawing Tool with no fill and add a Border size.